Geometry Nodes Straight Skeleton for Rooftops, almost finished
I need help with generating pitched rooftops out of 2D shapes. I am working to create a geonodes system to experience city planning free for laypeople.
I am trying to recreate a simple limited verison of the the Straight Skeleton Addon, having it directly as a geometry node setup.
I got the center points of the faces through the dual mesh operation, now I only need the extruded edges (the roof skin) to get positioned/merged to the nearest of those center points. I got all inputs already, I just cant get it to move. I tried nearest and sample nodes but cant wrap my head around it.
In short: 3rd image as illustration, upper vert of each edge needs to be moved to the nearest point.
I am stuck and would apprechiate any help or input!





This is a slightly modified version of that solution: Extruding Roofs out of Surface in Geo Nodes.

Note, however, that this variant does not represent a true “straight skeleton”, but merely a simplified solution as you intended, which achieves the goal you described:


Capture the position of each face.
Subdivide the mesh using the Subdivide node.
Create a selection of those faces that are adjacent to fewer than three faces and combine it with those points that are adjacent to three or more points. Due to the previous subdivision of the mesh, this selection contains the points that represent the sloping roofs at the short edges and that have to be moved to the face center afterwards.
Create a selection that either contains the previously created selection or those points that are adjacent to more than three faces. This selection represents the ridge of the roof that needs to be moved up.
Extrude the mesh (with an Offset of $0$) and move the sloped ends to the previously captured face positions and then move the whole ridge upwards.
Triangulate the mesh along the longest diagonal so that the roof has correct edges, but only on those faces that are no longer planar due to the points being moved up.
Merge the vertices.
(Optional) Additionally use the Decimate modifier to remove the excess edges.

(Blender 4.2.0+)

Thank you so much!!!!! ❤
